# How to tell xmllint not to change <tag></tag> to <tag/>

Tags: command-line, xml

I accept that it's standard to convert `<tag></tag>` to `<tag/>` but the client wants it in the former layout, not the latter. I've looked at various options for `xmllint` and cannot figure out what's needed.

Alternatively, is there something else other than `xmllint` that could be used?

Comment: What are you using `xmllint` for?

Comment: To format an output from a bit of code that talks to Xero.

Comment: Do you have a DTD for the XML? The standard (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml) section 3.1, [44] suggests that the empty tag format  (<tag/>) should only be used if the DTD defines the tag as EMPTY. If the DTD does define it as empty, I'm not sure what the next step would be. If the DTD does *not* define it as empty, then maybe ask xmllint to be more standards compliant?

Comment: Maybe try `xmllint --format foo.xml | xmllint --c14n -`

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 1):

`xmllint` has options that can be used to produce the desired output. From the help:

> ```
> --c14n : save in W3C canonical format v1.0 (with comments)   
> --c14n11 : save in W3C canonical format v1.1 (with comments)
> --exc-c14n : save in W3C exclusive canonical format (with comments)
> ```

Using any one of these would work

```
xmllint --c14n test.xml
```

Unfortunately, combining several formatting options in one `xmllint` call does not seem to work, so if you e.g. additionally want to use `--format` to have `xmllint` reformat/reindent the output, you will need to pipe the output from the first `xmllint` call into a second one. When doing this, it seems that `xmllint` requires the `-` stdin redirect be at the end of the command.

Example:

For `test.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outer><inner/></outer>
```

the command

```
xmllint --format test.xml | xmllint --c14n -
```

produces the output

```
<outer>
  <inner></inner>
</outer>
```

Notes:

- since the `--format` option would collapse the expanded empty tag again, the order of the options in the pipe matters
- the above options remove the [xml declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl) / omit it in the first line of the output